# Crypto trading bot with Binance, error from callback <bound method (takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given)

Tags: python, binance

The bot takes certain data from www.testnet.binancefuture.com> the information I am getting are bid and ask, historical candles, contracts, balances, place, cancel and order status. The callback methods are on_open, on_error, on_close, on_message + Channel subscription. Here is the code and the error

**class BinanceFuturesClient:**

```
    def __init__(self, public_key: str, secret_key: str, testnet: bool):
    if testnet:
        self._base_url = "https://testnet.binancefuture.com"
        self._wss_url = "wss://stream.binancefuture.com/ws"
    else:
        self._base_url = "https://fapi.binance.com"
        self._wss_url = "wss://fstream.binance.com/ws"

    self._public_key = public_key
    self._secret_key = secret_key

    self._headers = {'X-MBX-APIKEY': self._public_key}

    self.contracts = self.get_contracts()
    self.balances = self.get_balances()

    self.prices = dict()
    self.strategies: typing.Dict[int, typing.Union[TechnicalStrategy, BreakoutStrategy]] = dict()

    self.logs = []

    self._ws_id = 1
    self._ws = None

    t = threading.Thread(target=self._start_ws)
    t.start()

    logger.info("Binance Futures Client successfully initialized")

def _add_log(self, msg: str):
    logger.info("%s", msg)
    self.logs.append({"log": msg, "displayed": False})

def _generate_signature(self, data: typing.Dict) -> str:
    return hmac.new(self._secret_key.encode(), urlencode(data).encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

def _make_request(self, method: str, endpoint: str, data: typing.Dict):
    if method == "GET":
        try:
            response = requests.get(self._base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self._headers)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Connection error while making %s request to %s: %s", method, endpoint, e)
            return None

    elif method == "POST":
        try:
            response = requests.post(self._base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self._headers)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Connection error while making %s request to %s: %s", method, endpoint, e)
            return None

    elif method == "DELETE":
        try:
            response = requests.delete(self._base_url + endpoint, params=data, headers=self._headers)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Connection error while making %s request to %s: %s", method, endpoint, e)
            return None
    else:
        raise ValueError()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        logger.error("Error while making %s request to %s: %s (error code %s)",
                     method, endpoint, response.json(), response.status_code)
        return None

def get_contracts(self) -> typing.Dict[str, Contract]:
    exchange_info = self._make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo", dict())

    contracts = dict()

    if exchange_info is not None:
        for contract_data in exchange_info['symbols']:
            if contract_data['marginAsset'] != "BUSD":
                contracts[contract_data['symbol']] = Contract(contract_data, "binance")

    return contracts

def get_historical_candles(self, contract: Contract, interval: str) -> typing.List[Candle]:
    data = dict()
    data['symbol'] = contract.symbol
    data['interval'] = interval
    data['limit'] = 1000

    raw_candles = self._make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/klines", data)

    candles = []

    if raw_candles is not None:
        for c in raw_candles:
            candles.append(Candle(c, interval, "binance"))

    return candles

def get_bid_ask(self, contract: Contract) -> typing.Dict[str, float]:
    data = dict()
    data['symbol'] = contract.symbol
    ob_data = self._make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/ticker/bookTicker", data)

    if ob_data is not None:
        if contract.symbol not in self.prices:
            self.prices[contract.symbol] = {'bid': float(ob_data['bidPrice']), 'ask': float(ob_data['askPrice'])}
        else:
            self.prices[contract.symbol]['bid'] = float(ob_data['bidPrice'])
            self.prices[contract.symbol]['ask'] = float(ob_data['askPrice'])

        return self.prices[contract.symbol]

def get_balances(self) -> typing.Dict[str, Balance]:
    data = dict()
    data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    data['signature'] = self._generate_signature(data)

    balances = dict()

    account_data = self._make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/account", data)

    if account_data is not None:
        for a in account_data['assets']:
            balances[a['asset']] = Balance(a, "binance")

    return balances

def place_order(self, contract: Contract, order_type: str, quantity: float, side: str, price=None, tif=None) -> OrderStatus:
    data = dict()
    data['symbol'] = contract.symbol
    data['side'] = side.upper()
    data['quantity'] = round(round(quantity / contract.lot_size) * contract.lot_size, 8)
    data['type'] = order_type

    if price is not None:
        data['price'] = round(round(price / contract.tick_size) * contract.tick_size, 8)

    if tif is not None:
        data['timeInForce'] = tif

    data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    data['signature'] = self._generate_signature(data)

    order_status = self._make_request("POST", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

    if order_status is not None:
        order_status = OrderStatus(order_status, "binance")

    return order_status

def cancel_order(self, contract: Contract, order_id: int) -> OrderStatus:

    data = dict()
    data['orderId'] = order_id
    data['symbol'] = contract.symbol

    data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    data['signature'] = self._generate_signature(data)

    order_status = self._make_request("DELETE", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

    if order_status is not None:
        order_status = OrderStatus(order_status, "binance")

    return order_status

def get_order_status(self, contract: Contract, order_id: int) -> OrderStatus:

    data = dict()
    data['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    data['symbol'] = contract.symbol
    data['orderId'] = order_id
    data['signature'] = self._generate_signature(data)

    order_status = self._make_request("GET", "/fapi/v1/order", data)

    if order_status is not None:
        order_status = OrderStatus(order_status, "binance")

    return order_status

def _start_ws(self):
    self._ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self._wss_url, on_open=self._on_open, on_close=self._on_close,
                                     on_error=self._on_error, on_message=self._on_message)

    while True:
        try:
            self._ws.run_forever()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Binance error in run_forever() method: %s", e)
        time.sleep(2)

def _on_open(self, ws):
    logger.info("Binance connection opened")

    self.subscribe_channel(list(self.contracts.values()), "bookTicker")
    self.subscribe_channel(list(self.contracts.values()), "aggTrade")

def _on_close(self, ws):
    logger.warning("Binance Websocket connection closed")

def _on_error(self, ws, msg: str):
    logger.error("Binance connection error: %s", msg)

def _on_message(self, ws, msg: str):

    data = json.loads(msg)

    if "e" in data:
        if data['e'] == "bookTicker":

            symbol = data['s']

            if symbol not in self.prices:
                self.prices[symbol] = {'bid': float(data['b']), 'ask': float(data['a'])}
            else:
                self.prices[symbol]['bid'] = float(data['b'])
                self.prices[symbol]['ask'] = float(data['a'])

            # PNL Calculation

            try:
                for b_index, strat in self.strategies.items():
                    if strat.contract.symbol == symbol:
                        for trade in strat.trades:
                            if trade.status == "open" and trade.entry_price is not None:
                                if trade.side == "long":
                                    trade.pnl = (self.prices[symbol]['bid'] - trade.entry_price) * trade.quantity
                                elif trade.side == "short":
                                    trade.pnl = (trade.entry_price - self.prices[symbol]['ask']) * trade.quantity
            except RuntimeError as e:
                logger.error("Error while looping through the Binance strategies: %s", e)

        if data['e'] == "aggTrade":

            symbol = data['s']

            for key, strat in self.strategies.items():
                if strat.contract.symbol == symbol:
                    res = strat.parse_trades(float(data['p']), float(data['q']), data['T'])
                    strat.check_trade(res)

def subscribe_channel(self, contracts: typing.List[Contract], channel: str):
    data = dict()
    data['method'] = "SUBSCRIBE"
    data['params'] = []

    for contract in contracts:
        data['params'].append(contract.symbol.lower() + "@" + channel)
    data['id'] = self._ws_id

    try:
        self._ws.send(json.dumps(data))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Websocket error while subscribing to %s %s updates: %s", len(contracts), channel, e)

    self._ws_id += 1

def get_trade_size(self, contract: Contract, price: float, balance_pct: float):

    balance = self.get_balances()
    if balance is not None:
        if 'USDT' in balance:
            balance = balance['USDT'].wallet_balance
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None

    trade_size = (balance * balance_pct / 100) / price

    trade_size = round(round(trade_size / contract.lot_size) * contract.lot_size, 8)

    logger.info("Binance Futures current USDT balance = %s, trade size = %s", balance, trade_size)

    return trade_size
```

**The error after data:**

> error from callback <bound method BinanceFuturesClient._on_close of
> <connectors.binance_futures.BinanceFuturesClient object at
> 0x000002B05C6B57C0>>: _on_close() takes 2 positional arguments but 4
> were given

I did everything as in the "Udemy Cryptocurrency Trading Bot with a User Interface in Python" course. I can't figure out what's causing the error. I will be immensely grateful for any hints!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

you've got to add the args and kwargs, it looks like this.
After you add them there'll be no errors

```
def _on_close(self, ws, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.warning('Websocket connection closed')
    self.ws_connected = False
```